# imagePickerController error selecting a Photo

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm using imagePickerController, but when i select an imagen got an Error:

**fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value**

i dont know why because im unwrapping the value with the **if let**

```
  func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {

    if let img = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
        photoImageView.image = img
    }

    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does the error occurs at the line

```
photoImageView.image = img
```

In this case it might be that photoImageView is nil (it is often an implicitly unwrapped optional).

**Updated from comments:**

Please check that `photoImageView` is an `@IBOutlet` and it is connected to an UIImageView on the storyboard. If you are creating it programmatically, try adding it to a view in the window before setting the image.

Comment: yes, It is what I saw, it breaks at that point. How i can solve this?

Comment: Make sure `photoImageView` is an IBOutlet and it is connected to an UIImageView on the storyboard. If you are creating it programmatically, try adding it to a view in the window before setting the image.

Comment: @EnekoAlonso you are right! i had de IBOulet property, but it was disconnected to the storyboard! Thanks!

Comment: Glad to help. I've updated @nameCensored response with the solution, since he first pointed out where the problem was. Isaac, please mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe anything wrong with VC calling. This code works fine:

```
let picker = UIImagePickerController()
            picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary
            picker.allowsEditing  = false
            picker.delegate = self
            self.presentViewController(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)



func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
    let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
    productImageView.image = image
    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```